# Set path for java sdk

Tags: java, registry, environment-variables

I'm trying to set the `JAVA_PATH` in Windows, but I still can't access `javac` in command prompt.

What I've done so far is: I have added "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\" to the environment variable called `path`. I have also checked in the registers that the string is the same there. Still, when I try to compile a program in the command prompt, or even try to `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, there is nothing but errors.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I forgot to restart command prompt. Now it all works fine!

Comment: Did you restart your console/OS after setting this value?

Comment: What exactly means 'nothing but errors'?

Comment: @Pshemo you don't have to restart the console I think. And I am sure you don't have to restart OS.

Comment: Are you sure you are not l;ooking for %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: I did restart my computer, but I forgot to check if it worked. I feel so stupid now. Everything works. Thanks!

Comment: @ManojAwasthi If I remember correctly it may depend on OS. But I may be remembering outdated information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the command prompt would be enough. No need to restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to restart your computer :)

Answer (score 0):

Case Sensitivity is one the possible reason .Instead of Variable "path" try using "PATH" (uppercase).